# How to reliably pass options to git rev-parse

Tags: git

I have a tool that runs this command:

```
git rev-parse --path-format=absolute --git-common-dir
```

However its output is different depending on the git version! On older versions of git (e.g. 2.26) there is no `--path-format` option so it just prints out that option, like this:

```
$ git rev-parse --path-format=absolute --git-common-dir
--path-format=absolute
/path/to/repo/.git
```

On versions of git that support `--path-format` it works fine and only prints the second line.

How can I tell git "this is an option; please print an error if you don't understand it"? Is there something similar to how well-designed CLI tools let you do `foo --option -- file`.

Comment: Hmm for now I've just gone with checking the git version. `--path-format` was introduced in Git 2.31.0. Not ideal.

Comment: Yes, I introduced it for exactly the purpose you're trying to use it for (`--git-common-dir`).  As far as I know, there is no alternative to using it other than to do the canonicalization yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you *want the effect of the option*, you have no real choices here.  Well, you have two or three, but none of them are what I would call "real" choices:

1. Assume that all Git versions are recent (or force this to be the case) and just use the option.
2. Assume that all Git versions are old and avoid the option: use a workaround, such as running `realpath`, assuming that's suitable.
3. Check the version, and use the option when available and a workaround otherwise.

The *check version* step method is also your choice: see if `git rev-parse` spits the option back out, or run `git --version` first.  In shell scripts, here is a way to use `git --version`:

```
# Returns true if Git version is at least x and y
# ($1 and $2 respectively).  Returns false otherwise.
git_version_atleast() {
    local major="$1" minor="$2" saveIFS="$IFS"
    IFS=" ." # split words at space and dot
    set -- $(git --version)
    IFS="$saveIFS"
    shift 2 # discard "git" and "version"
    test "$1" -gt "$major" -o "$1" -eq "$major" -a "$2" -ge "$minor"
}
```

Use as, e.g.:

```
if git_version_atleast 2 31; then
    # git rev-parse behaves
else
    # use workaround
fi
```

This could be fancied up a bit to `set "$@"` after modifying `IFS`, before creating `major` and `minor` from `$1` and `$2`, so that you can invoke it as `if git_version_atleast 2.31`.  Note that this depends on `-a` having higher precedence than `-o` in `test` (which it does, but you might want to parenthesize).

Given that you need a workaround for old versions, I'd go with either #1 or #2 myself: use #2 until #1 is possible.  Use #3 only if the workaround has issues.